# Rails - should link text be set in controller or view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm battling with how much logic should be in a controller and how much in a view?

For example, I have a 'toggle' link that turns a filter on and off. The result is a link with some text depending on the state of the toggle, and whether a query param added or not.

i.e. in one state

```
<%= link_to 'With filter', polymorphic_path(Thing, { filtered: 1 }) %>
```

and in the other state

```
<%= link_to 'Without filter', polymorphic_path(Thing, {}) %>
```

I'm torn between either assigning the link label and query params in the controller, so then I'll have no logic in the view, and both variables are set in the controller...

```
<%= link_to @filter_link_text, polymorphic_path(Thing, @filter_link_params) %>
```

but it seems like I'm putting too much view logic into the controller

or the controller sets up a simple flag and leaves the rest to the view...

```
<% if @offer_filter %>
  <%= link_to 'With filter', polymorphic_path(Thing, { filtered: 1 }) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Without filter', polymorphic_path(Thing, {}) %>
<% end %>
```

Could translations help?

Thanks.

Comment: In what depends the value of `@filter_link_params`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma  it's a toggle - if the controller sees it set in `params`, then `@filter_link_params` will be empty.  If `params` is empty, `@filter_link_params` will be set.

Comment: I might be answering my own question here, though... what if later I decide to refactor the UI so it's no longer a link.  I might add another filter, and then maybe a set of checkboxes with an overall 'filter' button?  That should all be view related. Perhaps all the controller should do is pass the current state of the filter(s) to the view?

Comment: What is `Thing`? A class or an object?

Comment: @Schwern  `Thing` is a model class. I know I could have used `things_path` but I wanted to keep this example simple, my actual code has nested resources and `polymorphic_path` is much easier to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options, it depends on the circumstances.

You *do not* want to put view text into the controller. No `@filter_link_text`. The controller connects models to views. The view handles how things are displayed.

Simplest is what you already suggested, the controller sets a flag which the view uses.

```
<% if @offer_filter %>
  <%= link_to 'With filter', polymorphic_path(@thing, { filtered: 1 }) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Without filter', polymorphic_path(@thing, {}) %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can move this into a [partial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). Move the code into `app/views/shared/_filtered_thing.html.erb` and render it in your view. This simplifies your view and allows sharing of view code.

```
<%= render 'shared/filtered_thing' %>
```

---

A middle ground is to use a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). A decorator is a thin wrapper around a model which lets you add and change its behavior specific to a certain use. It avoids fattening up the model with a bunch of view code.

[`draper`](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) implements decorators and ties in well with Rails. It uses a very similar problem as its example.

```
class ThingDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def filter_toggle_link(filtered)
    if filtered
      # h allows access to the Rails helper methods
      h.link_to 'With filter', h.polymorphic_path(self, { filtered: 1 })
    else
      h.link_to 'Without filter', h.polymorphic_path(self, {})
    end
  end
end
```

Now your view calls that method on the decorated object.

```
<%= @thing.filter_toggle_link(@offer_filter) %>
```

You can also add flags to your decorator. For example, if you needed to set filtered per object.

```
class ThingDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  attr_accessor :filtered

  def filter_toggle_link
    if filtered?
      # h allows access to the Rails helper methods
      h.link_to 'With filter', h.polymorphic_path(self, { filtered: 1 })
    else
      h.link_to 'Without filter', h.polymorphic_path(self, {})
    end
  end

  def filtered?
    filtered
  end
end

# In the controller
@thing.filtered = true

# In the view
<%= @thing.filter_toggle_link %>
```

A big advantage of a decorator over a view partial is you can unit test a decorator.

Partials and decorators open up more ways to keep your view logic well factored and keeping it from bloating your controllers and models.

Comment: Partials are not really that difficult to test in isolation. You just use `ActionView::TestCase` or a view spec in RSpec and pass in the locals and then write assertions about the resulting HTML. Admittedly I don't write them very often as I try to cover views with feature specs and keep the complexity down.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern. Actually, I may not have explained myself fully  The point of the filter is to limit the scope of the index in the controller, not on individual instances.  I take your point about the partials - yes, I will definitely do that.